# Multiple if statements in MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

If you have multiple if statements within a MySQL trigger, what is the best approach?

Currently my SQL looks like this:

```
IF NOT (NEW.status <=> OLD.status) THEN
  {my sql}

ELSEIF NOT (NEW.actual <=> OLD.actual) THEN
  {my sql}
END IF
```

On first sight this seems to work. However, I noticed that when multiple of the (else)if statements are true, only the first one gets executed (just like in PHP, for example).

How can I just use multiple if's, not necessarily elseif's, so that more than 1 statement is executed? Creating multiple triggers with the same action is not possible, at least that is what phpMyAdmin shows. Putting multiple if's in one trigger results in errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out. Instead of using the visual GUI in phpMyAdmin for creating triggers, I used plain SQL.

So I used this SQL:

```
delimiter //
create t1
after update
on my_table
for each row
    begin
        IF (NEW.status <> OLD.status) THEN
            {your sql}
        END IF;

        IF (NEW.actual <> OLD.actual) THEN
            {your sql}
        END IF;     
    end;//
delimiter ;
```

Which works fine. When lookup the trigger up in the phpMyAdmin GUI, I noticed it is because of the `begin` and `end;` which have to be added.

Comment: I noticed it is because of the  begin and end; which have to be added.....That's the real point

Answer (score 0):

```
if(NEW.shift = 0 )then

SELECT `max_morning` , `count_morning` into @max_morning , @count_morning FROM `count_reserve` where `date` = NEW.date_reserve;
if(@count_morning is NULL and @max_morning is NULL) then

  select `max_morning` , `max_evening` into @max_morning , @max_evening   from `work_time` where `day` = new.day;

    insert into `count_reserve` (`date`, `count_morning` ,      `count_evening`,`from_morning`, `to_morning`, `max_morning`, `from_evening`, `to_evening`, `max_evening` , `status_morning` , `status_evening`) values (NEW.date_reserve , 1 , 0 , NULL, NULL, @max_morning , NULL, NULL, @max_evening ,1, 1);


end if
end if
```

Answer (score -1):

Use like this:

```
 IF (NEW.status <> OLD.status) THEN
    <statement>
 ELSEIF (NEW.actual <> OLD.actual) THEN
     <statement>
 END IF;
```

Comment: That produces the same? When the first IF is true, the elseif isn't executed.