# Facing Error while creating a MYSQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS TRIGGER_BEFORE_USERS_MAUALEXPIRY_USEREXPIRAY_UPDATE $$


CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_BEFORE_USERS_MAUALEXPIRY_USEREXPIRAY_UPDATE 


    BEFORE UPDATE ON USERS
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
    IF @DISABLE_TRIGGERS IS NULL THEN
        IF  NOT (NEW.MANUALEXPIRATIONDATE <=> OLD.MANUALEXPIRATIONDATE) THEN

            SET NEW.CUSTOMFIELD2 = NEW.MANUALEXPIRATIONDATE;
        IF  NOT(NEW.USEREXPIRYDATE <=> OLD.USEREXPIRYDATE)  THEN

            SET NEW.CUSTOMFIELD3 = NEW.USEREXPIRYDATE;
        END IF;
        END IF;         

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 17

Comment: Missing closing the first `IF`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_BEFORE_USERS_MAUALEXPIRY_USEREXPIRAY_UPDATE     

    BEFORE UPDATE ON USERS
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
    IF @DISABLE_TRIGGERS IS NULL THEN
        IF  NOT (NEW.MANUALEXPIRATIONDATE <=> OLD.MANUALEXPIRATIONDATE) THEN    
            SET NEW.CUSTOMFIELD2 = NEW.MANUALEXPIRATIONDATE;
        END IF;
        IF  NOT(NEW.USEREXPIRYDATE <=> OLD.USEREXPIRYDATE)  THEN    
            SET NEW.CUSTOMFIELD3 = NEW.USEREXPIRYDATE;
        END IF;    
    END IF;
END
$$
```

Comment: Thank you jurgen but i want to compare both the conditions. if i use  elseif i wil loose one.

Comment: Thank you jurgens i got the answer there is a similar thread for this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847702/multiple-if-statements-in-mysql-trigger